# sql query for inserting data and updating when existing column value is present

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure like below:

```
customer dtmf sound
1         1     3
1.        2     4
1         3     3
1         4     6
1         5     2
2         6     4
2         7     8
```

In my use case, dtmf must be a unique value for each customer while sound and customer can repeat. I am trying to write an SQL query that will insert into the table (values) with the below logic.

Logic:
GIVEN customer, dtmf, and sound value

1. Get all rows for a given customer id.
2. For the customer id, check if the given dtmf value exists.
3. If it exists, update the sound value while keeping dtmf and customer same
4. If it does not exist, insert a new row with the customer, dtmf, and sound values.

This is what I currently have right now:

```
var sql2 = `INSERT INTO ivrs_dests (dtmf, sound) VALUES (${dtmf_id}, ${sound_id}) ON DUPLICATE KEY`;
```

Missing the where statement but thats pretty self explanatory. I don't think Duplicate Key can work because dtmf is not a key. Do I have to make dtmf a key for this to work or is there another way?

Let me know!

Comment: Is it mysql or sql server ?

Comment: @AmitVerma mysql

Comment: Please correct your tags then as you have tagged both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can put a unique index on the combination of customer and dtmf: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX customer_dtmf ON ivrs_dests (customer, dtmf);`

Then you can use an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause as you suspected. This is because:

> If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value **in a UNIQUE index** or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.

[MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

`INSERT INTO ivrs_dests (customer, dtmf, sound) VALUES (${customer_id}, ${dtmf_id}, ${sound_id}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sound = ${sound_id};`